# Shouldn't higher r values be inversely related with effect size?

Tags: effect-size, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, pearson-r

I'm conducting a Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test and read that the r from Pearson Correlation is good for determining an effect size.

Logically this does not make sense to me as the higher the effect size the greater the effect of an intervention. And yet the higher the r value the more linear a relationship two variables have. If two variables were identical they'd have a perfect relationship and so in a study identical pre and post values would represent 0 effect and yet have a r value of 1.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: I think you've read something about the correlation between the indicator variable (group membership, so 0s and 1s) and the values (the groups). If you just have two groups, you don't have any particular relationship between the values in the groups (or even groups with the same size), but you can find the correlation between group membership and the values in the group.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave. I tried deciphering what you meant, but would you mind expanding?

Comment: I think I was thinking of a normal scatter plot with pre as x axis and post as y axis but I think that was my error as the difference between my pre and post scores is the DV and the intervention is my IV. Instead should I think of it as I have my pre and post categories on the x axis and the test scores on the y axis so I'll have to vertical scatter plots. And the r value would be if you had to fit a line from one scatter plot to the next?